# displaying multiple dataset relations in one datagridview

Tags: c#

I have two xml codes from two database tables, that I read them with XmlReaders in C#.
Then i've set DataSets and fill them with the readers and merge them. Now I want to define relation between them to display whole data in a DataGridView. But I can't see anything in my datagrid. No errors and no outputs.

This is my C# code:

```
XmlReader reader1 = XmlReader.Create("http://example.com/ShowTaxonomy.php/");
XmlReader reader2 = XmlReader.Create("http://example.com/ShowTerms.php/");
ds1.ReadXml(reader1);
ds2.ReadXml(reader2);
ds2.Merge(ds1);
newRelation = new DataRelation("Buy", ds2.Tables["terms"].Columns["term_id"], ds2.Tables["term_taxonomy"].Columns["term_id"]);
```

I've also tried this one but it doesn't work too:

```
ds2.Relations.Add("Buy", ds2.Tables["d3CwX_terms"].Columns["term_id"], ds2.Tables["d3CwX_term_taxonomy"].Columns["term_id"]);
ds2.Relations.Add(newRelation);
```

I use this code to fill my datagrid:

```
frm.dgv.DataSource = ds2.Relations["Buy"];
```

What can i do to have output?
Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Try,

dataSet.AcceptChanges();

Or

ds1.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { ds1.Tables[0].Columns["empkey"] };
ds2.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { ds2.Tables[0].Columns["empkey"] };

// this is the critical line
ds1.Merge(ds2, true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);

Comment: try this  frm.dgv.DataSource = ds2;